How to run VBA code in powerpoint if my slides are all autotransition
My powerpoint contains 5 slides. The first slide is just a coverpage with a textbox "Welcome to presentation". It has audio speech. After the speech, it will auto transition to slide 2.
The slide 2 is a multiple choice question. It has a question with 4 choices. I use optionbutton (activex control) for the 4 choices. Only 1 selection can be made as there is only one correct answer among the the 4 choices. It will show you made the correct choice or not before it auto transit to slide 3.
The slide 3 is the same as slide 2 with a multiple question and auto transit after choice made.
The slide 4 is also the same as slide 2 and slide 3.
The slide 5, I want to display a text box with the total correct score out of 3.
I try to insert the code in slide 5 but it does not run. I think if the slides are manually click, the code will run.
**Dim score1 As Integer
Dim score2 As Integer
Dim score3 As Integer
Dim ttlscore As Integer
score1 = 0
score2 = 0
score3 = 0
If ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("OptionButton1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then
score1 = 1
End If
If ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("OptionButton4").OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then
score2 = 1
End If
If ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("OptionButton4").OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then
score3 = 1
End If
ttlscore = score1 + score2 + score3
ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes("scoremsg").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "The score is " & ttlscore & "."**

Question is how to make it run and display the text when my slideshow autotransit to slide 5? can here attached the powerpoint for best illustration? I have tried to insert into onslideshowpagechange but it does not seems to work as my slide will not auto transit.

You've dumped some code that is incomplete and out of context, and are asking us why it isn't working. That's impossible to say, as you're missing the entire context of where the code is located. Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. That MRE should be complete enough that it can be copied and pasted into a presentation with 5 slides and run to reproduce the problem.

You could leave, on the side of the slide, an empty shape. If the question is correct, that would be marked (an "x", a 1 or whatever). At the end, a loop would count how many correct answers were provided.\

To Ken White, hi good day. I learn by doing and so may not have the foundation. I have created slides that can calculate scores and display by clicking the activeX control button. Would you mind demo to me using two slide. the first one is a multiple choice question that contains only two activeX control optionbutton (e.g. True or false) selection. e.g. Am I a human? True or False.  The user can only select either true or false. When the slide auto transition to the next slide, the result is displayed on the second slide. E.g. The score is 1 if answer on the previous slide is correct.

To Ken White, In additional, just like to add on. The first slide may not need much vba as a textbox can be added with the question written. and two optionbuttons. and another two textbox containing the text TRUE and FALSE. Let say's the slide will auto transit to second slide 10 sec after the slide auto transit. That means the user will only click once on the option button. The user will not click anything else on the first slide and the slide will auto go to the second slide after 10 secs and display the result.

To Oran G. Utan, the main challenge is the slides are auto transit without user clicking anything except only once on the optionbutton. Same as the example in my above comment, I am not sure whether the second slide code will run and display the result. For example my vba in my second slide general declaration will be " If shape.1 = 1 then score is 1. else score is 0. endif. Msgbox ("score"). Will the code run automatically once the slideshow move the slide from the first slide to the second slide?
